# Passing ID of websocket connection between testcases (Common Test) , Erlang

Tags: http, websocket, erlang, cowboy, gun

Who can help me?
I have server that based on websockets.
I want to test API using common tests (CT) passing connection ID between testcases and using only one connection for all testcases.
Test cases closes the connection.

Please, give me example if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you organize your test cases in groups and the groups in (test) suites, you can use the functions `init_per_suite/1`, `end_per_suite/1`, `init_per_group/2`, `end_per_group/2`, `init_per_testcase/2` and `end_per_test_case/2` to create and destroy all the resources you need, and keep them alive the necessary time. There is a `Config`[2](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/write_test_chapter.html) you can pass around using the `init`'s, and it is intended to be used for *run time* configuration.

If you have trouble to pass the information to your testcases, you can store them in a registered server (a simple loop reacting to a couple of requests) that you spawn at the right init_per_XXX level and destroy at the corresponding end_per_XXX.

See the example at [learnyousomeerlang](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/common-test-for-uncommon-tests)

Comment: I have function for creating websocket connection:<br/>
```open_ws_connection() ->
  {ok, Pid1} = gun:open(?WS_HOST, ?WS_PORT, ?WS_OPTS),
  {ok, http} = gun:await_up(Pid1),
  Ref1 = monitor(process, Pid1),
  StreamRef1 = gun:ws_upgrade(Pid1, ?WS_PATH, ?WS_HDRS, #{compress => true}),
  receive
    {gun_upgrade, Pid1, StreamRef1, [<<"websocket">>], _} ->
      #{pid => Pid1, monitor_ref => Ref1, stream_ref => StreamRef1}
  after ?WS_TIMEOUT ->
    #{error => timeout}
  end,
  #{connection_pid => Pid1, connection_ref => Ref1}.```
<br/>
<br/>

Comment: In init_per_suite called function:<br/> 
{ok, StartedApps} = application:ensure_all_started(?APP_NAME)
I have testcases: testcase1, testcase2.<p>
In testcases I try to send request:<p>
```SendMsgReq = jiffy:encode(Req),
  gun:ws_send(PID, {text, SendMsgReq})```<p>

But when I use PID of connection then I get response:
```{error, timeout}```
When connection was created in testcase then all works fine.